# Use live template with ideavim

Tags: rider, ideavim

I'm trying to use rider with ideavim, and there's a bit annoying for working with live template.
If I use "if" template, it goes to insert mode and couldn't overwrite the default value.
[Here's the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUe53.jpg) 
It's annoying that need to remove the value everytime using the template.
However, for some reason I don't want to remove the value name in live template.
I saw some video can stay in edit mode when using live template, but I couldn't find where to setting.
Hope anyone could help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem for change idearefactormode from keep to select mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).